# Добавить элемент в многомерный массив (php)

Tags: php, массивы

Есть многомерный массив $catalog с **неограниченной** вложенностью. Например,

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => Раздел 1
            [11] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Раздел 1.1
                )
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => Раздел 2
            [21] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Раздел 2.1
                    [211] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => Раздел 2.1.1
                        )
                )
            [22] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Раздел 2.2
                )
        )
)
```

И есть массив $keys с определенным набором ключей для первого массива $catalog. Например,

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2
    [1] => 21
)
```

Используя эти примеры, как мне добавить в $catalog[2][21] новый элемент? Чтобы в массиве появилось:

```
[212] => Array
    (
        [name] => Раздел 2.1.2
    )
```

Comment: а в чем проблема?

Answer (score -1):

Ок, нам нужно будет найти максимальный ключ на данном уровне вложенности и добавить к нему единицу, это и будет новый ключ.

```
$in_keys = [1,17,173];
$last_in_key = $in_keys[sizeof($in_keys) - 1];

$curr_el = $catalog;
foreach($in_keys => $k) {
    $curr_el = $curr_el[$k];
}

$keys = [];
foreach ($curr_el as $k => $v) {
    if (is_numeric($k)) {
        $keys[] = $k;
    }
}

$max_key = sizeof($keys) > 0 ? max($keys) : $last_in_key * 10;
$new_key = $max_key + 1;

$curr_el[$new_key] = $new_element;
```

Comment: кэп, у человека произвольный массив ключей на входе `[2,21,211,2114]` и так далее.

Comment: да нету у него этих константых `[2][21]`, может быть ведь и `1,17,173`. Надо по ключам массива пройти по всему "дереву" и в конец добавить то, что требуется.